# Generate SSH key on windows via command to specify email address

Tags: windows, ssh, command-line, ssh-keys

I have generated my keys using PuttyGen but need to be able to specify exactly the email address used with the following command but this doesn't work as I get an 'is not recognized as an internal or external command error'

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "joebloggs@mycompany.com"
```

Can anyone assist in running this command on Windows 10?

Comment: On Window you can using Cygwin. This is good terminal for window https://www.cygwin.com. It includes multiple package ex: ssh, nano ....

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wMnDpTWDLg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use PuTTYgen to generate a key with those settings.

For the key type `-t rsa` you have to select `SSH-2 RSA`
and for the email / comment `-C "joebloggs@mycompany.com"` you have to set the `Key comment` field to `joebloggs@mycompany.com`

[image: Example 1]

After clicking `Generate` your can get your public key from the `Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file` field (this is the same as `id_rsa.pub` when generated with `ssh-keygen`)

If you also need the private key to be saved in OpenSSH format just go to `Conversions > Export OpenSSH key` (this is the same as `id_rsa` when generated with `ssh-keygen`)

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Perfect answer @saibotu